# How can I convert the below snippet to Java 8 features?

Tags: java, java-8

I have POJO Employee which has list of Skills as shown below:-

```
public class Skills {

    private String language;
    private double versions;

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public double getVersions() {
        return versions;
    }

    public void setVersions(double versions) {
        this.versions = versions;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.List;

public class Employee {

    private long empId;
    private String empName;
    private String empAddress;
    private double salary;
    private List<Skills> skills;

    public List<Skills> getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    public void setSkills(List<Skills> skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }

    public long getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(long empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public String getEmpAddress() {
        return empAddress;
    }

    public void setEmpAddress(String empAddress) {
        this.empAddress = empAddress;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "empId=" + empId +
                ", empName='" + empName + '\'' +
                ", empAddress='" + empAddress + '\'' +
                ", salary=" + salary +
                '}';
    }

    public Employee(long empId, String empName, String empAddress, double salary, List<Skills> skills) {
        this.empId = empId;
        this.empName = empName;
        this.empAddress = empAddress;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.skills = skills;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to do the below:-

```
 List<Employee> javaEmpList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Employee emp : empList) {

            for (Skills skill : emp.getSkills()) {

                if (skill.getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("Java")) {
                    javaEmpList.add(emp);
                }
            }
        }
```

I am trying to convert this implementation by using Java 8 features. Can someone please help me with the same? I am new to Java 8. I tried using streams + filter + map combination but I am not able to achieve the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to `Stream` over the `List<Employee>`, use `filter()` to keep only `Employee`s having the Java skill, and `collect()` the filtered `Employee`s into a new `List`.

Note that this is not the exact same behavior as your nested loops, but I assumed you don't really want to add the same `Employee` multiple times to the output `List`.

```
List<Employee> javaEmpList =
    empList.stream()
           .filter(emp -> emp.getSkills()
                             .stream()
                             .anyMatch(skill -> skill.getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("Java")))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Not the exact same behaviour - if an employee has two matching skills they are added twice. Also, both examples are rather ... inefficient.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes, I mentioned the difference in behavior. I doubt the intent was to add the same Employee multiple times. It's more likely the skills list will not contain the same skill multiple times. Otherwise, the original loops should probably be fixed.

Comment: Could you please help us with your solution which resolves the 'added twice' issue? @BoristheSpider

Comment: @CodeMaster that issue exists only in your original code, not in the code of my answer.

Comment: @CodeMaster One can always use a `Set`, which gets rid of duplicates automatically. But it's more efficient to terminate the stream once a match has been found, like `anyMatch` does.

Comment: Can maybe use a set instead of a list to avoid the duplicate employee addition issue even if the same skill is added more than once in the list of skills.

Comment: @BoristheSpider you are talking about inefficient.. Would you mind providing an efficient solution?

Comment: @CodeMaster you can use a Set, but you don't have to (unless your input `List<Employee>` may contain duplicate `Employee`s which you wish to eliminate). The suggested Stream pipeline can add each Employee of the input List at most once to the output List.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate to Eran's solution would be to map each skill's `language` for an `employee` to its instance and then filter the entries just with required language. Post which you can collect the collection of values based on the requirement of duplicates or unique. This could be achieved as :

```
List<Employee> employeesWithJavaSkills = employeeList.stream()
        .flatMap(employee -> employee.getSkills().stream()
                .map(skills -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(skills.getLanguage(), employee)))
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Java"))
        .map(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Collectors.toSet() for unique employees
```